# Extracting html from different tabs of a website

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I have python 3.7 code to try and extract soccer stats from the following website (https://www.whoscored.com/Matches/1294545/LiveStatistics/Germany-Bundesliga-2018-2019-Bayern-Munich-Hoffenheim). Although the code seems to be extracting all of the stats listed under the Summary list, the stats under Offensive, Passing and Defensive don't seem to appear in within the HTML of the **scraped** data at all. Please note that instead of "MY USER AGENT", I actually have the correct user agent for my ip address that I searched up on google.
Here is the code I used:

```
import re
import requests
from ast import literal_eval
import random
import xlsxwriter
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.whoscored.com/Matches/1294545/LiveStatistics/Germany-Bundesliga-2018-2019-Bayern-Munich-Hoffenheim'

html = 'Request unsuccessful.'
while 'Request unsuccessful' in html:
    res = requests.get(
        url,
        headers={
            "user-agent": "MY USER AGENT",
            }
        )
    res.raise_for_status()
    html = res.text
    print(html)

match_data = re.search('var matchStats = ([^;]+)', html, flags=re.MULTILINE).group(1)
match_data_clean = match_data.replace(',,,',',').replace(',,',',')

stats = literal_eval(match_data_clean)
match_data = match_data_clean.split(',')
match_data1 = []
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('match_stats1.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

for i in match_data:
    match_data1.append(i.replace("[","").replace("]","").replace("'",""))

row = 0
for i in match_data1:
    print(i)
    worksheet.write(row, 1, i)
    row = row + 1
workbook.close()
```

Comment: page may use JavaScript to add this data but BS can't run JavaScript. You may need Selenium to control web browser which can run JavaScript. Or you can try to find url used by JavaScript to load data and then use it with requests.

Comment: in DevTools in Chrome/Firefox I see it use JavaScript/AJAX to load data in JSON format from [this link](https://www.whoscored.com/StatisticsFeed/1/GetMatchCentrePlayerStatistics?category=offensive&subcategory=all&statsAccumulationType=0&isCurrent=true&playerId=&teamIds=37&matchId=1294545&stageId=&tournamentOptions=&sortBy=&sortAscending=&age=&ageComparisonType=&appearances=&appearancesComparisonType=&field=&nationality=&positionOptions=&timeOfTheGameEnd=&timeOfTheGameStart=&isMinApp=&page=&includeZeroValues=&numberOfPlayersToPick=) but you may not see it if you connect from different portal.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to parse any html, they call endpoint:

```
https://www.whoscored.com/StatisticsFeed/1/GetMatchCentrePlayerStatistics
```

To obtain all the data they are displaying, here is my code:

```
import requests
import json


category = 'offensive' # defensive, passing, summary
headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36'
}

# all the filters, sorts etc are configured here.
params = (
    ('category', category),
    ('subcategory', 'all'),
    ('statsAccumulationType', '0'),
    ('isCurrent', 'true'),
    ('playerId', ''),
    ('teamIds', '37'),
    ('matchId', '1294545'),
    ('stageId', ''),
    ('tournamentOptions', ''),
    ('sortBy', ''),
    ('sortAscending', ''),
    ('age', ''),
    ('ageComparisonType', ''),
    ('appearances', ''),
    ('appearancesComparisonType', ''),
    ('field', ''),
    ('nationality', ''),
    ('positionOptions', ''),
    ('timeOfTheGameEnd', ''),
    ('timeOfTheGameStart', ''),
    ('isMinApp', ''),
    ('page', ''),
    ('includeZeroValues', ''),
    ('numberOfPlayersToPick', ''),
)

response = requests.get('https://www.whoscored.com/StatisticsFeed/1/GetMatchCentrePlayerStatistics', headers=headers, params=params)

json_data = json.loads(response.text)
print(json_data)
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error with your code and when using my own user agent - raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)